# How to get the request payload from a PATCH request in express

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js

I'm using Ember.js alongside an Express webserver. The default JSONApi adapter calls update records with a `PATCH` request to the server setting the `Request Payload` in the request to the server.

I'm having a hard time getting that data out of the request on my express server

Here is an example request Ember is sending to the server

[image]

The relevant code for the express server looks like this

```
app.route('/tags/:id')
  ...
  .patch(tag.updateTag);

// UpdateTag

function updateTag(req,res) {
  Tag.findById({_id: req.params.id}, (err,tag) => {
    if(err) res.send(err);
    Object.assign(tag, req.body).save((err,tag) => {
      if(err) res.send(err);

      res.json(TagSerializer.serialize(tag));
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. In express I'm also using the `jsonapi-serializer` npm module to do serialization and deserialization

Turns out I need to do my deserialization and in it's callback use the data to update with *rolls eyes*

```
function updateTag(req,res) {
  TagDeserializer.deserialize(req.body,(err,deserializedTag)=>{
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      Tag.findById({_id: req.params.id}, (err,returnedTag) => {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        Object.assign(returnedTag, deserializedTag).save((err,updatedTag) => {
          if(err) res.send(err);

          res.json(TagSerializer.serialize(updatedTag));
        });
      });
    }
  })
}
```